# Isometric deformation implies $ J^TJ=I$

Tags: isometry, jacobian

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^3$ be an isometric transfomation. Then $J^TJ=I_3$, where  $J $ is the jacobian matrix of  $f$ , and $T$ refers to the transpose of a matrix.

Can some one help me see how this holds?

Note: this is not a homework at all, I was reading [this](http://igt.ip.uca.fr/encov/publications/pubfiles/2015_Bartoli_etal_PAMI_sft.pdf) article in computer vision  where they state this proposition. No proof is provided, I try to search or derive it by myself, but I fail.

Comment: It's true, but the way the author presents it is a bit obscure. Basically, all isometries on $\mathbb R^n$ must be linear, hence its matrix is real orthogonal. This is a well-known result that is not hard to prove. See [this handout](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/isometryRn.pdf) for instance (the result is proved as corollary 4.4). The key is that on a Euclidean space, preservation of distance (norm) is equivalent to preservation of dot product. (This is no longer true in $\mathbb C^n$ and there are non-linear and non-differentiable isometries on it.)

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ preserves distances, then for every $x$ and every vector $h$, the difference $f(x+h)-f(x)$ has norm $\|h\|$. Let $J$ be the Jacobian matrix at $x$, which by definition has the property 
$$
Jh = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+ht)-f(x)}{t}
$$
Since $\|f(x+ht)-f(x)\| = |t|\|h\|$, it follows that $\|Jh\|=\|h\|$ for all $h$. In particular, the matrix norm of $J$ is $1$.

Recall the relation of norm and dot product: 
$$
\|h\|^2 = \|Jh\|^2 = \langle Jh, Jh\rangle = \left\langle J^TJh, h\right\rangle
\le \| J^TJh\| \|h\| \le \|h\|^2
$$
which also uses the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality  and the fact that $\|J^T\|=\|J\|$. Since we started and ended with $\|h^2\|^2$,  equality holds everywhere here, including the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The  Cauchy-Schwarz inequality turns into equality only when $J^TJh$ is   a scalar multiple of $h$. This multiple must be $1$ for the rest of things to be equal. So $J^TJh=h$ as claimed.